# how can i add the git credentials in to jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

hi team how can pass my github credentials in my jenkins declarative pipeline please helpme out how can i add my git hub credentials user name and password and url in my jenkins pipeline, if i add the user name and password if i add the password in to my pipeline some one how can i push my files in to my git using jenkins declarative pipeline .

i know how to use the jenkins syntax generator , but i want to know how to pass a credentials using jenkins declarative pipeline. please help any one

pipeline{
agent any
stages{
stage('git-log'){
// withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'ramesh-git', usernameVariable: 'raja12', passwordVariable: 'Rakae12')])
steps{
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'ramesh-git', usernameVariable: 'raja12', passwordVariable: 'Rakae12')])
sh 'git clone [https://github.com/trdy43/test-play.git'](https://github.com/trdy43/test-play.git%27)

```
    }
        
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As I see you are trying to use the `withCredentials` step, which is the right way use credentials in a pipeline script. Please edit your question and copy-paste the exact error message you get (text only). Also please try to format your code correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enter git credentials in jenkins pipeline code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915860/how-to-enter-git-credentials-in-jenkins-pipeline-code)

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your credentials on Jenkins Credentials Store.

Then you will be able to access your credentials with

```
pipeline {
    agent any 

    environment {
        MY_CREDENTIALS = credentials('my-credentials-on-jenkins')
    }
```

This will create and populate two environment variables: one for username MY_CREDENTIALS_USR, other for password MY_CREDENTIALS_PSW.

You can then access the environment variables by calling their names:

```
    stages {

        stage('Calling MY_CREDENTIALS') {
            steps {
                echo "username is $MY_CREDENTIALS_USR
                echo "password is $MY_CREDENTIALS_PSW
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your Git credentials on Jenkins Global Credentials Store.
I'm using this method.

```
stage('Checkout External Project'){
  steps{
  git branch: 'master',
  credentialsId: 'credid',
  url: 'git@bitbucket.org:muz******/react-app-jenkins.git'
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`'githubuserpwd'` being the credentials variable name that we given in Jenkins:

```
pipeline {

    agent any
    environment{
      github = credentials('githubuserpwd')
     }

    stages {

      stage('login to github'){
         steps{
           sh "docker login -u $github_USR -p $github_psw"
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: githubuserpwd is the credentials variable name that we given in jenkins