# How to enter git credentials in jenkins pipeline code

Tags: git, jenkins

Am having a Jenkins server running on GCP-Linux Vm, I want to access a code from git's private repo,
am trying to access it from my Jenkins pipeline code, how can I enter my git credentials in Jenkin pipeline code?

Answer (score 2):

you should share the pipeline you use for more specific answers.

As a general answer:

- If you use only one repo ( the one you are building ) you don't need to call the credentials in the pipeline.
  Just configure your credentials in jenkins credentials area and your job like this:

[image]

In this case no special reference in pipeline code is necessary

- If you want to clone a second repository in your build you can use inside your pipeline:

  pipeline {

  ```
    environment {
    gitCredentialId = 'Jenkins-Bitbucket' //defined in credentials area
    gitUrl = 'https://bitbucket.org/companyNameHere/repoNameHere.git'
    deployBranch = 'branch-name-here'
    }
    stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
        steps {
            git(
            url: gitUrl,
            credentialsId: gitCredentialId,
            branch: deployBranch
        )
        }
    }
  ```

  }
- to store credentials: manage jenkins > manage credentials > click on global domain > add credential . Make sure to put meaningful description and ids as this area tends to become a mess in time and it is hard to cleanup as you will never know what can be deleted.

[image]

Each credential will tell you where it is used:

[image]