# Is there a way to configure a Jenkins Linux Node/Slave at startup?

Tags: linux, bash, git, jenkins

UPDATE:
Maybe my question is not clear enough. I'm like trying to figure out a way for a Jenkins Linux Node/Slave to do something similar like a .bashrc file is doing when logging in with a user on Linux. The question is broader that just Git. I want to configure the Linux Node/Slave from the Jenkins Master. So when the Linux Node starts up, I want to execute some commands configured on the Jenkins Node.

---

Is there a way to execute some commands when a Jenkins Node starts up?

For instance:

```
git config --global http.extraHeader "Authorization: Basic ${B64_PAT}"
```

Or another thing we need to do on the Linux VM:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
git config --global credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath true
```

Is there a way to automate this on the configuration of a Jenkins Node?

Now we log in on the Linux VM with the same user and execute those commands once manually. But with every new Linux Node we need to execute those commands again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enter git credentials in jenkins pipeline code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915860/how-to-enter-git-credentials-in-jenkins-pipeline-code)

Comment: Hi Liam, no, that's a totally different question. I've seen that on a Jenkins Node you can inject environment variables. But what I want is to do on a Node what a .bashrc file does for instance. Maybe my question is not clear enough.

Comment: What is a "Jenkins Node"? `on the Linux VM` What linux? What VM technology?  Are you asking how to execute commands on linux startup? Is jenkins related to the question? There are ansible, puppet, foreman, ovirt, finally /etc/rc.local and systemd.

Comment: *I'm like trying to figure out a way for a Linux Node to do something similar like a .bashrc file is doing* so why don't you use the `bashrc` file? This question is really not clear at all

Comment: If you don't know what a Jenkins Node is, then why do you want the answer the question? It doesn't matter what linux or VM technology. I want to configure the Linux Slave/Node on the Jenkins Master.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [Startup trigger plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/startup-trigger-plugin/) that lets you start a job once a node goes online. Maybe you can do your configurations in that job and then run that job with the plugin automatically once it goes online?

The examples you give will store in global files on the machine, so I guess that will work for you. But note that it will run in a subshell so exported variables in there will not be available in other jobs. This can be a problem depending on what you need to do.

Comment: HI Veda, yes, that would be a possibility. We are now looking to create a job that does the configuration. And run it once on each VM. But I had rather found a solution that does this configuration on the Jenkins Node.

Comment: Regarding the variables, see `/etc/environment` etc.: https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages/environ.7.en.html , https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/systemd/environment.d.5.en.html etc.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration that you are describing would typically be achieved using a combination of Jenkins and configuration management tools like Ansible, Chef, Puppet, or Terraform.

A general outline of how you might accomplish this would be:

1. **Use a configuration management tool**: A configuration management tool can be used to provision and manage your Linux nodes. This tool can be used to run the initial setup commands that you mentioned (such as the `git config` commands) when the node is first provisioned.
2. **Use Jenkins to control the configuration management tool**: Jenkins can be used to run jobs that control the configuration management tool. For example, when a new node needs to be provisioned, a Jenkins job can be run that triggers the configuration management tool to provision and configure the new node.

For example, if you were using Ansible, you might create an Ansible playbook that includes tasks for running the `git config` commands. Then, in Jenkins, you could create a job that runs this Ansible playbook whenever a new node is provisioned.

As an example, an Ansible playbook might look like:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Set git config values
      git_config:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        value: "{{ item.value }}"
        scope: global
      with_items:
        - { name: 'http.extraHeader', value: "Authorization: Basic ${B64_PAT}" }
        - { name: 'credential.helper', value: 'manager' }
        - { name: 'credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath', value: 'true' }
...
```

In this playbook, the []`git_config` Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/git_config_module.html) is used to set the `git config` values. The `with_items` statement is used to set multiple `git config` values in a single task.

Then, in Jenkins, you could create a job that runs this playbook whenever a new node is provisioned. The exact steps to create this job would depend on your Jenkins setup, but it might involve adding a build step that runs a shell command like `ansible-playbook my_playbook.yml`.